# Good way to delete One Drive from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

Windows 10 One Drive is a nuisance and difficult to control when one has gigabytes of photos. I need to remove it from my computer and not get errors afterwards. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried going to Apps and Features and just uninstalling it?

Comment: I did that, yet footprints somehow remain.

Comment: Listing those "footprints" which remain may help us get you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following methods:

1. Open `Run` and insert `%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\`
2. Click `OK` to open folder named OneDrive
3. Find the folder with pure numbers in the folder, this number is the version number. If there are more than one, choose the one with the largest number and remember this number.
4. Open `Run` again and insert this code `%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(the version number)\OneDriveSetup /uninstall`
5. Then click `OK`
6. In the pop-up dialog box, click "Yes"
7. Reboot your machine
8. After rebooting, please open `Run` and insert `%localappdata%\Microsoft\`
9. Find the folder named with `OneDrive` and then right click it and select `Delete`. Now you have delete OneDrive completely.